In JavaScript, is there a way to create a custom thenable that automatically triggers some code after it has been awaited?
Consider the following code:


async function test(label) {
    console.log(`BEFORE: ${label}`);
    await waitForSomething(label);
    console.log(`AFTER: ${label}`);
}

function waitForSomething(label) {
    return {
        then(onFulfilled) {
            console.log(`FULFILL: ${label}`);
            onFulfilled();
        }
    }
}

console.log('START');
test('A');
test('B');
console.log('END');



It gives the following output:

START  
BEFORE: A  
BEFORE: B  
END  
FULFILL: A  
FULFILL: B  
AFTER: A  
AFTER: B

I would like AFTER A to trigger immediately after FULFILL A, in a synchronous way, which would give:

START  
BEFORE: A  
BEFORE: B  
END  
FULFILL: A  
AFTER: A  
FULFILL: B  
AFTER: B

The idea is that I'm writting a library with a global state that I want to stay consistent accross a chain of asynchronous calls written by the user. Because multiple chains may be running at the same time, I need to run some code before a call chain "resumes". I understand it may seem like a weird or bad idea at first glance, but this is a separate question. Is there a way to do that?
I've thought of returning an object with something like an unwrap method that would trigger the code, like:
(await waitForSomething(label)).unwrap();

But this forces the user to use unwrap() on all relevant calls, which is tedious. Moreover they may forget to do it and run into unexpected issues without understanding why.
EDIT: I will expand on the motivation behind this a bit further. Basically, the idea is to avoid having to pass a state parameter all the way down to the chain and have it accessible as a global variable.
Instead of doing:
async function test(state) {
    let input = await waitForUserInput();
    doSomethingWith(state, input);
}

function doSomethingWith(state, input) {
    // ...
}

I could do:
async function test() {
    let input = await waitForUserInput();
    doSomethingWith(input);
}

function doSomethingWith(input) {
    let state = MyLib.state;
    // ...
}

This allows to avoid having to carry state accross every single function call triggered by test. However since some of these functions are async, and since multiple of them can run at the same time, and since there is a different state for each root function (such as test), I need to set MyLib.state to the right value when an async function returns. Again, this is in the context of a library: the library provides the state to the test function and runs it, but test itself is written by the user.
EDIT 2: As pointed by user3840170, it turns out what I need is https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-context/, which is only at stage 2 of the proposal. So I guess that's just not possible for now.
EDIT 3 (SOLUTION): Alexander Nenashev suggested using queueMicrotask, which seems to do the trick! I've implemented it in my lib and so far it works as expected. Below the final code that produces the expected output:


async function test(label) {
    console.log(`BEFORE: ${label}`);
    await waitForSomething(label);
    console.log(`AFTER: ${label}`);
}

function waitForSomething(label) {
    return {
        then(onFulfilled) {
            queueMicrotask(() => console.log(`FULFILL: ${label}`));
            onFulfilled();
        }
    }
}

console.log('START');
test('A');
test('B');
console.log('END');




Hi! Would you update the question to give an example of what the output would be with the change you want? Just so we're completely clear on what you're asking.

"synchronous" like async function main() { console.log("START"); await test('A'); await test('B'); console.log("END") } ?

Why can’t you put it within the body of then?

I am struggling to understand the motivation behind this in general.

@T.J.Crowder I've added the desired output!

@user3840170 Because I will not be writting the body of then, the user will. I'm making a library that provides a set of asynchronous functions, and the users will be using them.

Are you perhaps trying to create a poor man’s https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-context/? I don’t think this is actually implementable conservatively (i.e. by a polyfill in user code, without global instrumentation). Better just pass the context object around.

@user3840170 Thanks I didn't know about this proposal, and yes it turns out this is exactly what I'm trying to do. So I guess it's not possible for now :(

Would it be acceptable for your use case to set up a queue of calls? So that you allow your users to make every calls in parallel, but internally, you block on the previous ones before executing the next ones? POC: https://jsfiddle.net/a2y1tpfh/

@Kaiido I thought about it, but it becomes a problem when the calls change based on a condition, like if (condition) doSomething(); else doSomethingElse();. It's always possible to get around it by making a function return the next function to add to the chain, but it forces this pattern to be propagated to the whole codebase which ultimately leads to unintuitive and unreadable code. I want this library to be as simple and straightforward to use as possible, so I don't think it would work well.

I'm not sure I follow. This should be transparent to the user. It's only affecting your lib's code. I suppose waitForSomething is truly async, and as such it currently doesn't ensure that the first promise returned would resolve before the next one. All that would change is that now this order would always be maintained. Maybe think of it as if you were transferring computation to a single Worker. Even though you can post multiple requests to it, it can still only proceed one sync operation at a time, and you have to wait for the previous ones to finish before getting the new results.

@Kaiido Yes, waitForSomething is truly async. An actual example is waitForUserInput that returns when the user performs the specified action. It can then chain to other waitForUserInput. Multiple functions that call to waitForUserInput can run at the same time, and since we're waiting for user input we have no way to know which one will resolve first.

If what you seek is indeed [tag:task-local-storage], then perhaps restrict your question to ask about that directly. That actually has some solutions, even if no portable ones. Hooking arbitrary code before a promise continuation is invoked seems like a much more powerful primitive, which may never be available at all.

I guess the goal isn't making the log in your desired order, but rather to preserve a state in an async call chain. You can queue a microtask restoring the state right after await. I guess a more elaborated solution is needed to cover all your needs:


async function test(label) {
    console.log(`BEFORE: ${state}`);
    await waitForSomething();
    console.log(`AFTER: ${label} => ${state}`);
    await waitForSomething();
    console.log(`AFTER 2: ${label} => ${state}`);
}

function waitForSomething() {
    let cached = state;
    return {
        then(onFulfilled) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(`FULFILL: ${cached}`);
              // call this before the callback, so the code after `await` would receive the proper state
              queueMicrotask(() => state = cached);
              onFulfilled();
            }, Math.random()*1000);
        }
    }
}

console.log('START');
let state = 'A'; // your MyLib.state 
test('A');
state = 'B';
test('B');
state = 'C';
test('C');
console.log('END');
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important}




Wow it seems to do the trick, amazing! I'm not too familiar with queueMicrotask, will this work regardless of how many async chains are running in parallel?

@symil seems so, I've added setTimeout() to simulate real async ops and C test.

@symil i've added a second await waitForSomething()

Thank you, I'll try to implement this today to see if everything works correctly.

@symil at least that's a starting point, your whole idea is quite interesting

@symil queueMicrotask() as the same as `Promise.resolve().then(), just cleaner

I've implemented the solution in my lib, and I've had no problem so far. Thanks a lot!

@symil glad to hear, it was interesting how it will be in a real-life scenario
